# Submitting prior art against US patent application

Tags: prior-art, pre-grant, indigenous, us20140134731

Reference to [US20140134731](https://www.google.co.in/patents/US20140134731)

I think the Patents office is slipshod or very keen on encouraging pirating and patenting of indigenous knowledge. There is NOTHING unique or special requiring any exercise of intelligence in saying Clerodendrum viscosum is used in India extensively to treat a method for treating cervical cancer and is used extensively in Ayurveda. These are well known facts. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerodendrum_infortunatum#Ayurvedic_and_Siddha_medicines, http://www.toxicologycentre.com/english/plants/Botanical/perigalam.html and many other resources that I was able to find by the simple act of googling. Is the patenting of traditional knowledge allowed when it is in use extensively. This is against Indian law also. This is an illegal act and should be rescinded forthwith.
This sort of incompetent action can lead to international conflict in patents and US strong arm methods may not work any more in this field.

will the patent office notice this fact and rescind the patent? How can i go about filing a complaint?

Comment: There are ways to get the USPTO to take a second look at a patent. (This is an application, not a patent) However, they do not rescind patents on their own initiative.

Answer (score 1):

This is a publication of an *application* for a patent. It is not a granted patent.

Answer (score 0):

As George points out, this is merely a published application.  It has not yet been examined or allowed.  For what it's worth, the inventor is an Indian national.

If you are concerned about its allowance, I recommend you work with one of the organizations that is dedicated to protecting indigenous knowledge and file a statement with the Patent Office.  They accept third party information.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i go about filing a complaint?

You can use EFS -WEB public submission for prior art to raise objection against it.

[EFS-WEB Unregistered filer](https://efs.uspto.gov/EFSWebUIUnregistered/EFSWebUnregistered)

[image]